# Interpret a Regression Analysis

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients, descriptive-statistics

I am not sure how to interpret this regression analysis. The R-square of the scatter plot is 1, even R=1, F and Sig value are both missing (empty). What does that imply? Can I say that there is a strong relationship between the independent and dependent var or is this indicating an error?
[image]

Comment: Context? To get a perfect fit like this, I'd bet you have the same variable on the left hand side of your regression as the right hand side. Or if this is simulated data, that you never added an error term. Or perhaps there's some purely mechanical relationship between your left hand side variable and your right hand side variables (like age ~ dateOfBirth year).

Comment: Thanks, it was an error from my part.. Both data (iR and DV) were the same when copied and pasted into IBM SPSS. I corrected the same. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

it looks like you have a perfect fit. If this is actual data, then something most likely went wrong. If this is simulated data, then this makes perfect sense. You can explore this further by making a scatterplot with your independent variable on the x-axis and your dependent variable on the y-axis.

Comment: It only makes sense for simulated data if @user39531 did not add any error term to the dependent variable.